# I'm making a renaming application in Android

Tags: android

## Andorid

I want to show progressdialog while doing renaming task. The dialog should appear after clicking rename button. However, the progress dialog appears after renaming function(loop) is ended. Here's my code

```
public void onRenameClicked(View v){
    ProgressTask task = new ProgressTask();
    task.execute();
    for(int i = 0; i < num_of_files; i++){
            rename(file[i]);
    }
}
```

and Here's innerclass to show dialog

```
class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>{
    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < item.size(); j++) {
            pd.setProgress(j);
            pd.setMessage((j) + "/" + item.size());
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pd.setTitle("변경중");
        pd.setMax(item.size());
        pd.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your renaming loop be inside `doInBackground()`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
       super.onProgressUpdate(values);
       pd.setProgress(values[0]);
       pd.setMessage((values[0]) + "/" + values[1]);
}
```

and

```
publishProgress(j, item.size());
```

in the `doInBackground()`. These modifications are required because the `setProgress` and `setMessage` must be executed in the UI thread not in the background one.

Comment: Also you need to change your class: AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void>. The type in the middle is the one for the progress updates.

Comment: yep @Thommy, agree

Comment: @Changs did it help?

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that you are calling your async task, with no data.. therfore its finishing quickly. You should probably pass in the list of files into the AsyncTask via arguments and then process those calls accordingly for each file **INSIDE** the AsyncTask and update the progress of the AsyncTask as you finish renaming files.